# How to create approval process for opportunity products?

Tags: salesforce, crm

I m doing some sample application where i had created discount field in opportunity product related list and i want to send an approval to the manager if discount range is more than 20% like that but while creating an approval process i m not able to select opportunity product, only opportunity object is visible so that my discount field is not visible over there..

so how can i send an apporval for discount if field is present in opportunity product related list of opportunity..

please suggest me as i m new to salesforce platform

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create a rollup field on opportunity of type count. Have a criteria like: discount > 20%.

Now in your approval process, check for this rollup field, if it is greater than 0 meaning that opportunity has a line item where discount is greater than 20%; that opportunity will be qualified for approval.

Comment: so simple. Seen many other ideas, this one is a true one liner!